# "Unable to access "Micro SD Card" - Not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: 16.04, sd-card, crouton

I have a micro SD card that I am trying to access to store documents. Currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Chromebook using Crouton.

I've been trying every solution I can find, including formatting the card to ext4

Regardless of my attempts, it still is saying "Unable to access" and "not authorized to perform operation".
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Crouton runs in a Chroot environment as a guest OS to Chrome OS. Because of this, it is **not allowed** to mount or unmount devices (since it is not the main OS). You need to mount it in Chrome OS, then it will be accessible in your Chroot. I know this because I *used* to be a Crouton user, though I don't use it anymore since I have moved to a dual-boot (which to be frank is better is every way because you don't experience permission denied errors like this).

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for your input. Is there a specific tutorial for dual booting a chromebook that you would recommend? Sorry, I am very new with Linux

Comment: @jcjurkas - Yes, I followed the guide at http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/projects/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux/ - this won't void warranty either since you are not opening up your Chromebook. Also, if the installation drops you to a boot> command shell, type help, followed by pressing enter twice